# Grunt Warning: watch ENOSPC, only on copied directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grunt-contrib-watch

I have seen other posts about this error, but feel that my use case is different.

I have a template repo that use for building map interactives.  Grunt runs fine when modifying the template, but when I copy the template directory and then try to run grunt from the copy I get the "Warning: watch ENOSPC" error.  I can disable Watch and the rest of grunt runs fine, but that adds a lot to my workflow.

Other posts about the error suggest that there is a file limit on what can be watched.  But seeing that everything works fine in the original template, it shouldn't be a matter of number of files since it should be the exact same file structure.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I should mention that there are all of 15 files in the directories I'm watching.